# Was "Merlin's beard!" an invention of Rowling's?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter* books, wizards frequently use "Merlin's beard!" expression.

Is this something that Rowling invented or does it have a history in fantasy literature before her?

The Wikia article on [Merlin's beard](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Merlin%27s_beard) does not seem to offer any details.

Comment: Not sure about that, but "Merlin's baggy Y fronts" was most certainly a Rowling invention. :p

Answer (score 19):

**TL;DR:**

- There was 1 case of using this phrase as exclamation, but in a *Romance* book (1992)
- There was 1 case of using this phrase in SFF book (1999, before JKR's first use in *Goblet of Fire* in 2000) but it was more of an oath than exclamation. Not sure if it counts or not. No other hits before *GoF* came out.

---

OK, so I [trawled through Google's Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Merlin%27s%20beard&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=50&share=), and lo and behold - the phrase WAS used before HP books came out:

[image]

---

Now, that by itself doesn't prove anything, since the phrase may have simply been used as non-exclamation. So I actually read through several pages of Google Book search.

Lo and behold, I found at least ONE instance of "Merlin's beard" being used as an exclamation, like in Harry Potter - but it seems it wasn't in speculative fiction:

> Entranced - Page 173 
>   books.google.com/books?isbn=0373097743
>   **Nora Roberts** - 1992 - ‎Snippet view - ‎More editions
>
> **By Merlin's beard**, you have it bad, Donovan, he thought as he chose a silver evening bag with an emerald clasp. His mother had once told him that love was more painful, more delightful and more unstoppable when it came unexpectedly.

I also found one (but ONLY one) SFF use of the phrase which can be considered to be an exclamation, but YMMV:

> The Immortal Regi Gressen - Page 152
>   books.google.com/books?isbn=1563151707
>   James H. Parcher - 1999 - ‎Snippet view
>
> **and by Merlin's beard**, someone put this Druid stone here just in time." "You and Assi don't plant any crops." "It's for everybody's crops, and fertility." Her most patronizing voice, you understand. "I thought you and Assi said three kids were ...

---

*NOTE: For possible etymology of the expression, English.SE has a [related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41240/what-does-merlins-beard-mean).*

Comment: I also have the feeling I it was used in Disney's [The Sword in the Stone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sword_in_the_Stone_(film)); I can _almost_ remember it being said in an accent where "by" sounds like "great" (like, "great Merlin's beard!")...

Comment: @Izkata - that should be an answer if you can find any proof.

Comment: No luck for me finding a script

Comment: @Izkata - Are you thinking of this quote from the scene with Archimedes and the airplane model? Merlin: "It would have worked if... if it weren't for this infernal beard!"

Comment: @JohnP 'Tis certainly possible

Comment: **Trolled** through? Or *trawled*? Changed to what I think you meant.

Comment: @Wikis - *gets out his troll club made out of hobbit bones*

Answer (score 10):

In Umberto Eco's *The Name of the Rose*, (1980), “Merlin's Beard” is also used as an expression of surprise by the principal protagonist.

Comment: The quote in my copy is "*“Undoubtedly. Therefore only certain verses are good. Strange. As if they had had fewer than fifty: thirty or twenty . . . **Oh, by the beard of Merlin!**”*" rather than "*Merlin's beard*"

Answer (score 1):

I believe "Great Merlin's Beard!" was used by Dr Bombay in "Bewitched". So much of Harry Potter came from that show - witches walking through walls, mortals and witches married, spells being thrown like wand-fighting in a position suitable for the katana, etc.

Comment: Do you have any evidence of it being used in that show?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only use of Merlin was from [Samantha the Dressmaker](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0523183/) -  **Endora:** *By the great beard of Merlin! Are you still on this seamstress kick?*